# Importing only specific extensions from a module

Tags: swift, module, swift-extensions

Say I have some extension in module `A`:

```
public extension String {
    func foo() { ... }
}
```

In module `B`, I would like to sometimes import individual extensions (or files), just like I can `import struct`, `import enum`, ...

Neither of

```
import struct A.String
import func A.String.foo
```

works, and there does not seem to be a keyword geared towards extensions.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read this: [apple doc modules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID4)
but its not possible, you can only use the Access Levels